# Let $x_1,...,x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $0 \not\in conv\{x_1,...,x_k\}$. Show there is a $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $c^Tx_i \geq1$ for all $i\in[k]$.

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, convex-hulls

Let $x_1,...,x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and assume $0 \not\in conv\{x_1,...,x_k\}$. Prove that there must be some $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $c^Tx_i \geq1$ for all $i\in[k]$.

Relevant Theorem: Hyperplane Separation Theorem

Let $P,Q$ be closed, convex, bounded, and disjoint in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a $b$ such that $c^Tx<b<c^Ty$ for all $x\in P,\;y\in Q$.

We can look at an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$
[image]

Let the origin $\{0\}$ be $P$ and the $conv(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ be $Q$. The hyperplane separation theorem gives is the green line $H$ where $H=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\;c^Tz=b\}$ and $c^T$ is the normal vector (drawn in light blue). Then maybe we can make $b$ be the vector representing $1$? I'm not sure where to continue from here.

Comment: Hello, can you edit your post to share with us some of your thoughts and attmps, that is to give us more context?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Sorry, I should have given more context from the beginning. I think I should be trying to connect the hyperplane separation theorem to $c^Tx_i\geq1$ somehow, but that is where I am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From hyperplane separation theorem, we know there exists a $b$ and $\hat{c}$ such that

$$0<b< \hat{c}^Ty ,\forall y \in conv(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$$

Let $c = \frac1b \hat{c}$, then we have

$$c^Tx_i > 1, \forall i \in [k]$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got the conclusion that $c^Tx_i\geq1$? Thanks

Comment: If we have $c^Tx_i > 1$, we have $c^Tx_i \ge 1$. that is if a number is bigger than $1$, then the number is bigger or equal to $1$.

Comment: I understand that part, but I don't understand how you got that from letting $c=\frac{1}{b}\hat{c}$.

Comment: I just divide the previous inequality by $b$.

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean now. I was a little confused by the $y$, but then I realized that it's just part of the hyperplane separation theorem.